# I aim to increase resolution of a image using NN, I tried using 'dnn_superres' in opencv but I get an error

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, neural-network, resolution

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

# Create an SR object
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# Read image
image = cv2.imread('IMG.png') #it is in the same path of this code

# Read the desired model
path = "ESPCN_x3.pb" #downloaded from a github
sr.readModel('D:\Folder\Folder Python\ESPCN_x3.pb')

# Set the desired model and scale to get correct pre- and post-processing
sr.setModel("espcn", 3)

# Upscale the image
result = sr.upsample(image)

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", sr.upsample(image))
```

The Error which I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Folder\Folder Python\superres.py", line 21, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", sr.upsample(image))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-5rb_9df3\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp:1243: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !(m.empty() && fixedType() && fixedSize()) && "Can't reallocate empty Mat with locked layout (probably due to misused 'const' modifier)" in function 'cv::_OutputArray::create'
```

Comment: I am not sure what is going on but it worked for me after downgrading to opencv 4.5.0

Comment: did you check whether `cv2.imread` worked? I got the same error when specifying a wrong path, so `image` was NoneType